# Temporizadores individual en objetos dinámicos con JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo un problema con los temporizadores que he creado, me explico:

Estoy mostrando creando varios contenedores de manera dinámica, donde cada uno de ellos tiene un contador de tiempo, el cual al hacer `click` en el botón, este despliega el temporizador y te dice cuanto tiempo falta... Sin embargo, este tiene 2 problemas:

- solo funciona para el primer elemento.
- Si le das click a otro elemento, el contador avanzará mas rápido, es decir, si le aumentaran +1 a su velocidad  `contador = contador+2` y así…

Mis dudas son:
¿Cómo hacer que cada contador al hacer click, comience con su conteo regresivo? Y
¿Cómo puedo evitar el que aumente de velocidad con respecto a cada click?

Adjunto código

```js
const createData = () => {
  const dealers = [
    {
      id: 1,
      time: "8:00",
      status: "Disponible",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      time: "8:30",
      status: "Disponible",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      time: "9:00",
      status: "Disponible",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      time: "9:30",
      status: "Disponible",
    }
  ];

  //Creando un foreach para mostrar todos los datos
  dealers.forEach(function (dealer) {
    const template = `
      <div id="dealerContainer" class="riders-panel">
        <div class="container">
          <h3>${dealer.time}</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
          <p>#${dealer.id}</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="container">
          <button class="btn active">${dealer.status}</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
    app.innerHTML += template;

    //Obteniendo los botones y haciendo la delegacion de eventos
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

    const handleClick = (event) => {
      if (!event.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.contains("disabled")) {
        event.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add("disabled");
        event.target.classList.add("disabled");
        event.target.innerHTML = "Ocupado";
        if (!event.target.disabled) {
          event.target.disabled = true;
          timerDealers();
        }
        console.log(`El boton ha sido desactivado`);
      } else {
        event.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove("disabled");
        event.target.classList.remove("disabled");
        event.target.innerHTML = "Disponible";

        console.log(`El boton ha sido activado`);
      }
    };

    //Solo agrega los eventos a cada boton
    buttons.forEach(function (button) {
      button.addEventListener("click", handleClick, true);
    });
  });
};

//Creando el contador
let secs = 1800;
function timerDealers() {
  const element = document.querySelector("h3");
  let mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  let remSec = secs % 60;
  if (remSec < 10) {
    remSec = "0" + remSec;
  }

  if (mins < 10) {
    mins = "0" + mins;
  }

  element.innerHTML = `Disponible en: ${mins}:${remSec} minutos`;
  setTimeout(timerDealers, 1000);
  if (secs > 0) {
    console.log(secs);
    secs--;
  } else {
    alert("El tiempo ha terminado");
    clearInterval(timerDealers);
    secs = 1800;
  }
}

createData();
```

```css
.riders {
  width: 800px;
  min-width: 340px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.riders-panel {
  width: 800px;
  min-width: 340px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.riders-panel.disabled {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
    <main class="riders" id="app"></main>
```

:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usas `querySelector`, el cual devuelve sólo el primer elemento, por eso no funcionan los otros botones.

Por otro lado, al no tener separados los contadores obtienes esos resultados inesperados. Puedes aprovechar el mismo arreglo `dealers` para almacenar también su respectivo contador.

Aquí mi consejo es no pivotear sobre vista (el HTML) si no -seguir pivoteado- sobre el modelo (el arreglo `dealers`).

```js
const TIEMPO = 10;
const dealers = [
    {
      id: 1,
      time: "8:00",
      status: "Disponible",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      time: "8:30",
      status: "Disponible",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      time: "9:00",
      status: "Disponible",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      time: "9:30",
      status: "Disponible",
    }
  ];

//Creando un foreach para mostrar todos los datos
dealers.forEach(function (dealer) {
    const template = `
      <div id="dealerContainer${dealer.id}" class="riders-panel">
        <div class="container">
          <h3>${dealer.time}</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
          <p>#${dealer.id}</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="container">
          <button class="btn active" 
                  dealer-id="${dealer.id}"
                  onclick="handleClick(event)"
          >${dealer.status}</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
    app.innerHTML += template;
});
  
function handleClick(event){
    let dealerId = event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("dealer-id").value;
    console.log("handleClick",dealerId);
    if(!event.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.contains("disabled")) {
        event.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add("disabled");
        event.target.classList.add("disabled");
        event.target.innerHTML = "Ocupado";
        if (!event.target.disabled) {
            event.target.disabled = true;
            dealers.forEach( 
                function(d){ 
                    if(d.id == dealerId)
                        d.timer = TIEMPO;
                }
            );
        }
        console.log(`El boton ha sido desactivado`);
    } 
};
  
setInterval( 
    function(){
        dealers.forEach(
            function(d,i){
                if(d.timer != null){
                    let e = document.getElementById("dealerContainer"+d.id);
                    console.log(d.id+":",d.timer);

                    let mins = Math.floor(d.timer / 60);
                    let remSec = d.timer % 60;

                    let h3 = e.querySelector("h3");
                    h3.innerHTML = `Disponible en: ${String(mins).padStart(2,"0")}:${String(remSec).padStart(2,"0")} minutos`;

                    if (d.timer > 0) {
                        d.timer--;
                    } else {
                        alert("El tiempo ha terminado");
                        d.timer = null;
                        h3.innerHTML = d.time;
                        
                        let btn = e.querySelector(".btn");
                        btn.disabled = false;
                        btn.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove("disabled");
                        btn.classList.remove("disabled");
                        btn.innerHTML = "Disponible";
                        dealers[d.id].timer = null;
                        console.log(`El boton ha sido activado`);
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
, 1000
);
```

```css
.riders {
  width: 800px;
  min-width: 340px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.riders-panel {
  width: 800px;
  min-width: 340px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.riders-panel.disabled {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<main class="riders" id="app"></main>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, tengo dos preguntas: 1-Veo que sacaste los datos de la `const createData`¿Por qué? 2- ¿Por qué cuando `dealers[dealerId].timer = null` genera un error al llegar a 0 en el contador? Y como podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Los saqué simplemente por que no lo vi necesario para que corriera en el fragmento de código, y para que quedaran los datos, el manejador del click y el temporizador en el mismo ámbito, ya que hay comunicación entre ellos. En vez de lanzar varios timeouts (uno cada segundo) preferí crear sólo un temporizador para todos. Actualicé la respuesta corrigiendo el error, consideré mas apropiado -si no es que necesario- mover el código de la reactivación del botón al temporizador y se me pasó cambiar el nombre de la variable.

Comment: Comprendo lo del ámbito para ambas funciones, temporizador, los eventos y el setTimeout... Aun lo que me queda dudas es la reactividad. Toca leer eso por mi cuenta. Gracias por la explicación 3:

Answer (score 2):

tienes dos problemas:

1. El `<h3>` estas agarrando siempre el primero, lo que tienes es que pasarle el que este dentro del mismo contenedor del botón al que le diste click:

```javascript
// Necesitas pasar el <h3> que esta en el mismo contenedor que el
// boton al que le diste click
const element = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('h3');
timerDealers(element);
```

Y se lo pasas a la función `timerDealers`

2. El `secs` no puede ser global porque entonces lo vas a terminar compartiendo entre todos los contadores.

Aqui esta funcionando: https://jsbin.com/xapenec/5/edit?html,js,output